# How to configure coin-osi with mosek interface

Tags: mosek

I have downloaded the source code from http://www.coin-or.org/download/source/Osi/, and installed `Mosek 7`. How to configure the `coin-osi` with `Mosek` library? Could you give me some advice, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(1):Download mosek

```
   MOSEKDIR=/opt/mosek/7/tools/platform/linux64x86 
   sudo ln -sf /opt/mosek/7/tools/platform/linux64x86/bin/libmosek64.so.7.0 /opt/mosek/7/tools/platform/linux64x86/libmosek64.so
```

(2):Download Osi-0.106.6

```
   ./configure --with-mosek-incdir="$MOSEKDIR/h" --with-mosek-lib="$MOSEKDIR/bin/libmosek64.so" --disable-mosek-libcheck
```

(3): make